# Why do I get "object has no attribute 'exclude'" error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Trying to get a one to many query with filters I get an error:

```
def user_profile(request,pk):
    profileObj = Profile.objects.get(id = pk)
    topSkill = Profile.skill_set.exclude(description__isnull=True)
    otherSkill = Profile.skill_set(description = "")
    context = {"profile":profileObj,'topSkills':topSkills,"otherSkills":otherSkills}
    return render(request, 'users/user_profile.html', context)
```

Error:

> 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'exclude'

My models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length= 300, null = True, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "profiles/", default = "profiles/user-default.png", null = True, blank = True)
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    social_linkedIn = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null = True, blank = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4, unique = True, primary_key = True, editable = False)

    def __str__(self): #Django will call __unicode__ when it needs to render an object in a context where a string representation is needed
        return str(self.user.username)
    
class Skill(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: You write: `Profile.skill_set.exclude(...)`, perhaps you mean to write `profileObj.skill_set.exclude(...)`? The code you wrote really doesn't make any sense since you could have otherwise simply written `Skill.objects.exclude(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I have following suggestions including one already stated by [@AbdulAzizBarkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434432/why-do-i-get-object-has-no-attribute-exclude-error#comment131399805_74434432) in the above comment:

1. Better to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).
2. Directly exclude items from model rather than using reverse relations.

So the view should be:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def user_profile(request,pk):
    profileObj = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=pk)
    topSkill = Skill.objects.exclude(description__isnull=True)
    otherSkill = Skill.objects.exclude(description = "")
    context = {"profile":profileObj,'topSkills':topSkills,"otherSkills":otherSkills}
    return render(request, 'users/user_profile.html', context)
```

However, I did not understand the logic of `Skill.objects.exclude(description="")` as the `topSkill` already excludes those items which are null=True.